# PHP Mongo Cursor loop fails with exception "Could not convert BSON document to a PHP variable"

Tags: php, mongodb

I am getting following cursor exception while looping from new PHP driver...

> "Could not convert BSON document to a PHP variable"

It works well with old PHP drivers.

Comment: Would you mind adding code? It is hard to tell where a problem might be when there is nothing to check for...

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue, it was due to bad character inside key of Mongodb document..
sample key: "PR�NO"...

Old PHP-Mongo driver handling it well but new driver version 1.1.8 throwing exception "Could not convert BSON document to a PHP variable"....